# Which one is more efficient in terms of boolean in java?

Tags: java, performance, if-statement, boolean, conditional-statements

Which one is more efficient in terms of boolean in java ?

```
Boolean boolean;
if(boolean == false) {}
```

OR

```
if(!boolean) {}
```

Comment: This is not a matter of efficiency but of readability. Got with what you think makes it easier to read your code, that is your coding style. If you are not working in something where every nanosecond counts, then do not bother to optimize stuff like that, just optimize stuff that improves the complexity class.

Comment: This question was asked before and it doesn't matter and opinion-based

Comment: Personally, I think you should avoid the first one like the plague. It's too easy to accidentally say `if(var = false)` instead. They produce identical bytecode though, so there's no performance difference.

Comment: Personally; I also try to avoid the second version. It is too easy to overlook the !. I very much prefer "positive" conditions over negative ones.

Comment: @resueman It's not so easy to ignore the warning you get. So, `==` is perfect (and in a case where the variable name is e.g. `statement` easier to understand: `statement==false` instead of `!statement`)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The code block:

```
if(!boolean) {}
```

Is a cleaner code which improves readability.

There is no performance improvement.

Answer (score 3):

The performance difference is entirely trivial; in fact, I'd imagine these both compile to the exact same [bytecode](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Java_bytecode) (which would mean zero performance difference). Go with whichever option you think looks cleaner.

Side note: "boolean" is a reserved word in Java, so you need a different variable name. Also, unless you need your boolean to act as an Object (it's very rare you'd need to do this), you should use the `boolean` primitive type instead of the `Boolean` object type; the `Boolean` object type has more memory overhead.

Answer (score 1):

The both are correct but the second more elegant:

```
  if(!boolean) {}
```

Answer (score 0):

> Which one is more efficient

Both methods will have same performance since `!b` and `b==false` are replaced by `ifne` at byte-code.

But second version

```
if (!b){...}
```

is **safer** because it avoids common mistake/typo when instead of `==` we will use `=` like

```
if (b = false){/* this code will never be executed */}
```

---

#### Proof for `Boolean`.

Lets see how this methods will be compiled:

```
public void t1(Boolean b) {
    if (b == false) {
        System.out.println("foo");
    }
}

public void t2(Boolean b) {
    if (!b) {
        System.out.println("foo");
    }
}
```

With little help of `javap -c NameOfClassWithTheseMethods` we are able to see that

`t1` will be compiled into

```
  public void t1(java.lang.Boolean);
    Code:
       0: aload_1
       1: invokevirtual #16                 // Method java/lang/Boolean.booleanValue:()Z
       4: ifne          15
       7: getstatic     #22                 // Field java/lang/System.out:Ljava/io/PrintStream;
      10: ldc           #28                 // String foo
      12: invokevirtual #30                 // Method java/io/PrintStream.println:(Ljava/lang/String;)V
      15: return
```

and `t2` into

```
  public void t2(java.lang.Boolean);
    Code:
       0: aload_1
       1: invokevirtual #16                 // Method java/lang/Boolean.booleanValue:()Z
       4: ifne          15
       7: getstatic     #22                 // Field java/lang/System.out:Ljava/io/PrintStream;
      10: ldc           #28                 // String foo
      12: invokevirtual #30                 // Method java/io/PrintStream.println:(Ljava/lang/String;)V
      15: return
```

So for both methods compiler generated same byte-code.

---

#### Proof for `boolean`.

If we recompile

```
public void b1(boolean b) {
    if (b == false) {
        System.out.println("foo");
    }
}

public void b2(boolean b) {
    if (!b) {
        System.out.println("foo");
    }
}
```

we will get:

```
  public void b1(boolean);
    Code:
       0: iload_1
       1: ifne          12
       4: getstatic     #22                 // Field java/lang/System.out:Ljava/io/PrintStream;
       7: ldc           #28                 // String foo
       9: invokevirtual #30                 // Method java/io/PrintStream.println:(Ljava/lang/String;)V
      12: return

  public void b2(boolean);
    Code:
       0: iload_1
       1: ifne          12
       4: getstatic     #22                 // Field java/lang/System.out:Ljava/io/PrintStream;
       7: ldc           #28                 // String foo
       9: invokevirtual #30                 // Method java/io/PrintStream.println:(Ljava/lang/String;)V
      12: return
```

So again compiler generated same byte-code.